# How to render a hdri on a separate layer

Tags: render-layers

What's the best way to combine 2 render layers with a HDRI background? I wanna have 3 layers and having one layer be denoised and have a separate layer just for the HDRI.

Comment: Simply using the environment pass should suffice I think for the hdri. Use alpha over to combine everything in the compositor.

Comment: So the environment pass does work, but I can't use alpha over without enabling the transparent setting which causes the hdr to be transparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If  you simply enable the environment pass in a renderlayer, or add a single renderlayer using an empty scene layer to do so, you can achieve what you would like if I understand correctly what you are trying to do.

You will need to use transparent background, as you will need to use an *[Alpha Over node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/alpha_over.html#alpha-over-node)* to combine the renderlayers to create the complete image.

Here is a simple example:

[image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

The sphere is on it's own scene/ renderlayer and not denoised, while the monkey and plane are also on their own layer, and denoised. As you asked for a separate layer, the hdri uses an empty layer with the environment pass enabled.

The critical part, as noted is using the environment pass to be able to retrieve the environment image after rendering.

Comment: @J.Jesse, you're welcome, if this resolved your issue, consider marking the answer as accepted to remove it from the unanswered list.

Comment: Do you mean delete the post, I'm not sure how to remove it from the unanswered list on mobile.

Comment: @J.Jesse, see [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in the help center. It is at your option to vote, accept, or neither.