# How to separate environment in Compositor without black cutouts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, world

Nice people of Blender SE.

I'm using Compositor to blur my HDRi ([as suggested by others on BSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34027/78972)).
Cycles render engine.

However, the environment behind objects isn't rendered, there's just a black cutout.
Therefore any applied blur results in an annoying black halo around objects.

*Black halo occuring when combining blurred environment with objects.*
[image]

Sure, I can render the environment separately, but it's not very practical when handling multiple scenes or animation.

**Question**
How can i separate the environment without these black cutouts?

Comment: You could create an additional view layer that has all collections disabled and therefore would only render the environment. Add another *Render Layer* in the compositor and select the view layer that only contains the environment. Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I found that reccomended [here on SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94146/78972) and also in the Blender manual, and it works reasonably well. But have you got any idea why are there those black cutouts? Just curious :).

Comment: Probably in order to compute the final image like this: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html

Comment: Well it seems using a separate view layer is the way to go here. I'll stop looking for another solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just curious :)
Because render View Layers doubles rendering if I'm right.

---

You can use existing setup, just ...

- add **Set Alpha** node and plug inverted Alpha to create transparency in BG
- and use **InPaint** node to recreate missing environment

*Note:
because of alpha antialiased edge, I added **Delete/Erode** node with value -1 to get rid of one pixel that did InPaint node job slightly darker*

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Great solution thanks! :). I had no idea about these nodes since I don't use compositor very much.